# How to default a DateTime object in the EditorFor box as today's date?

Tags: c#, html, twitter-bootstrap, razor, model-view-controller

I am trying to make the EditorFor bootstrap box default to today's date and be read-only, so that when the form is submitted, it will be today's date without the user having to manually enter it.

I have tried some methods, but the value just remains as "mm/dd/yyyy". I would like for it to say "09/05/2019" if they were submitting it today.

Here is the EditorFor box in the view

```
            <div class="form-group">
                @Html.LabelFor(model => model.postDate, htmlAttributes: new { 
                @class = "control-label col-md-2" })
                <div class="col-md-10">
                    @Html.EditorFor(model => model.postDate, new { htmlAttributes = new { @value = DateTime.Today.ToString("mm/dd/yyyy"), @readonly = "readonly" } })
                    @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.postDate, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
                </div>
            </div>
```

And here is the attribute in the model

```
    [DataType(DataType.Date)]
    public DateTime postDate { get; set; }
```

How can I get this to just be a box that shows today's date in the preferred format?

Comment: Did you try `public DateTime postDate { get; set; } = DateTime.Now.Date;`?

Comment: If I change the code for the date in the model to this, what would I need to change in my view? I just tried changing it in my model and it didn't work. @flydog57

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
@Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.postDate, new { @Value = DateTime.Today.ToString("MM/dd/yyyy"), @readonly = "readonly" })
```

Notice:

- The name of the method
- The `MM` in the format
- Capitalization of the `@Value` parameter

A different method is necessary because if you look at the [signature](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.web.mvc.html.editorextensions.editorfor?view=aspnet-mvc-5.2#System_Web_Mvc_Html_EditorExtensions_EditorFor__2_System_Web_Mvc_HtmlHelper___0__System_Linq_Expressions_Expression_System_Func___0___1___System_String_System_String_System_Object_) of `EditorFor`, it does not allow passing of HTML attributes.

The `MM` is the correct way of displaying the two digit month (as opposed to minutes).

Capitalization seems necessary for `@Value`. A lower case `@value` does not work for some reason.

Comment: @auburntotd: Happy to help! :-)